How to create a Gmail Label for mails received from a specific address to me that are not cc or bcc
How to create a Gmail Label for mails received from a specific address to me that are targeted directly to me and that I am not Cc or BCC?
I tried the following but it also returns CC
to:me from:(sender@domain.com) 

I can't figure out a way to do it so far.

It can be accomplished using the search syntax that follows in the filter's 'Has the words' ¹ field.
Search Syntax
to:me -cc:me -bcc:me from:(sender@domain.com)


Gmail interprets me to mean all email addresses associated with your Gmail account (eg. aliases, send-as, etc.). If you want to restrict it to a specific address, replace each me in the search above with the address.  For example, replace
to:me

with
to:(myaddress@gmail.com) 


In Gmail search, to includes any of the message recipient fields TO, CC, and BCC. That is why to specify the TO field alone, to must be paired with -cc and -bcc.
Gmail only populates the BCC field of an incoming message with your email address if it was sent using Google's servers: ²

A personal Gmail account, including any configured alias/send-as addresses.
A Google Workspace account (school/work/organization) including any alias/send-as addresses.


IMPORTANT: If Gmail is set to conversation view, any single message in a conversation that matches a manual search will cause the entire conversation to be returned, including any messages that do not match the search.

This issue does not apply to filters of incoming messages.
This issue does apply when saving a filter and it runs one-time against existing messages because the 'Also apply filter to matching messages' option is checked.
To perform a manual search or run a filter one-time while avoiding this behavior, temporarily disable conversation view.



Gmail Help Center Resources

Refine searches in Gmail
Search in Gmail
Create rules to filter your emails

 

¹ See additional 'Has the words' info with images in my answer about combining 'from' and 'to' with 'OR'
² Based on my tests and observations; I've found no documentation for this behavior.

that is amazing thank you! However, I do not understand, where to paste this line? My gmail has a line for "from" and a line for "to" etc.
I pasted this
to:me -cc:me -bcc:me from:(x@y.com)  in the search syntax but it still includes me where I am cc'd

I've updated the answer to clarify where to put the search as well as to better explain the impact of conversation view.  Let me know if this addresses the issue or not. Also, see more detailed explanation regarding 'Has the words' field
